# Using FFMPEG select video filter with -ss on input

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm currently using an ffmpeg command like this, where I want to select very particular video frames from between (say) 6 and 8 seconds into the video:

```
ffmpeg
  -t 10
  -i test/timer.mp4
  -ss 6
  -vf "select=eq(ceil(n * 1 / 29.97) + 1\, ceil((n+1) * 1 / 29.97)) * lt(n\, 8 * 29.97)"
  tmp/%07d.png
```

However, this makes ffmpeg decode the entire video up to 6s because the `-ss` comes after the `-i`. How can I change this command to still do the video filter based on *absolute* timestamp into the video? For instance,

```
ffmpeg
  -ss 6
  -t 4
  -i test/timer.mp4
  -vf "select=eq(ceil(n * 1 / 29.97) + 1\, ceil((n+1) * 1 / 29.97)) * lt(n\, 8 * 29.97)"
  tmp/%07d.png
```

Is *not* equivalent because `n` now refers to the frame number starting *after* 6s into the video. This ends up selecting different frames.

Any way to reference the input video's absolute timestamp or frame number when using `-ss` on it?

Comment: Are you trying to select frames whose presentation doesn't span seconds boundary?

Comment: @Gyan close - In this example, I want frames whose absolute presentation *does* span a seconds boundary. More generally I want to downsample to a certain fps in a very specific way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `-copyts` to convey source timestamps, but you won't be able to use `n` which references index of frames fed to the filter.

Assuming a constant rate 29.97 video stream, use

```
ffmpeg
  -ss 6 -to 10
  -copyts
  -i test/timer.mp4
  -vf "select='trunc(t+1001/30000+TB)-trunc(t)'" -vsync 0
  tmp/%07d.png
```

I've used the exact rational value for 29.97.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use some other variable like `t` (PTS time) instead. You might need to subtract with `start_t` etc to get time starting from zero. See https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#select_002c-aselect for all variables available with the select filter.

If your selecting a continuous range of frames then maybe the [trim](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#trim) filter is easier to use.

Comment: I've tried `start_t` and `t`, but it looks like `start_t` is always 0 when I use `-ss` before `-i`. I am not trying to select a continuous range of frames - more like select frames at a certain fps in a very specific way.

Comment: @mwlon i see, any difference if you use -copyts? about fps, could the fps, framerate or framestep filters be useful?